# Can I freeze mashed potatoes I bought at the grocery store?

Tags: potatoes

I have 2/ 2 pound pkgs of mashed potatoes I bought from the grocery store.  I find I won't be using both and wonder if I can safely freeze one of the packages?

Comment: While not directly your question, my experience freezing mashed potatoes is they can use just a little water after they're thawed on reheat.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course you can. You can already buy frozen mashed potatoes at places like Trader Joe's. I would either freeze them in a gladware type of plastic container or put in a freezer ziploc and squeeze out as much air as possible.